# Convert Value counts to saparate columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am receiving a dataframe from source which looks like this:

```
date          output
2023-01-25    A
2023-01-25    B
2023-01-25    B
2023-01-25    C
2023-01-25    C
2023-01-25    A
2023-01-25    B
     ...
2023-01-26    B
2023-01-26    C
2023-01-26    B
2023-01-26    B
2023-01-26    A
2023-01-26    C
2023-01-26    B
     ...
2023-01-27    C
2023-01-27    A
2023-01-27    A
2023-01-27    C
2023-01-27    B
2023-01-27    B
```

For my pipeline I need to transform this data.

After using `df.groupby('Date').output.value_counts()` I was able to get following result:

```
Date        output
2023-01-25  A             52
            B             28
            C             42
2023-01-26  A             47
            B             32
            C             36
2023-01-27  A             23
            B             67
            C             35
```

But for my pipeline I need dataframe in following structure:

```
Date        A              B              C
2023-01-25  52             28             42
2023-01-26  47             32             36
2023-01-27  23             67             35
```

How can I store all these value counts to its respective column so result looks like above?

Comment: `pd.crosstab(df['Date'], df['output'])`

Comment: You can do this on the original df: `df.pivot_table(index='date', columns='output', aggfunc=len)`